# What's the name of the header progess bar on websites?

Tags: html, scroll

I'm trying to find the term for the progress bar of headers some websites now have (particularly many Microsoft documentation websites now). It seems similar to the concept of Breadcrumbs but is either a distinct version of them or something separate. An example of that I mean is here: https://www.agiliq.com/blog/2018/07/using-django-on-windows-with-wsl/. If you scroll down the page you'll see the headers on the right with a bar alongside that moves as you scroll and notes where you are among the headers; that's what I'm talking about.

All similar search terms however (bar, breadcrumbs, headers, progress bar) have so many results for other irrelevant things that I can't seem to find the right phrase. My searching so far has landed me on breadcrumb-related sites that then discuss breadcrumbs in the header. After fairly exhaustive attempts my Google-fu has failed me; what should I be searching here?

Also, my interest is particularly oriented toward implementing the same thing in a Django/Wagtail website. I'd be happy to just get the name of what I should be searching for.

Comment: cref: https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/122/top-5-best-webpage-loading-progress-bar-javascript-plugins

Comment: I think they are called navbars. A navbar is a common term in web design that refers to a section that contains the hierarchy of the web page, and each website has its own design. However, in the website you provided, it seems to be a mix between a navbar and scroll indicator.

Comment: If you check the source code of that page, you will see a javascript "scrollspy.min.js". You can check this link as well :https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_scrollspy.asp

Comment: @NalinDobhal it's also a part of Bootstrap https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/scrollspy/

Comment: @AmineMessaoudi thanks for the info. I don't use bootstrap so I wasn't aware of that. It's good to learn something new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scroll indicator or Scrollspy :)

Answer (score 0):

The correct term is: "Scroll indicator"

Comment: You could have given this answer as a comment, or elaborate your answers. Keep up the contribution!

Comment: This seems to be true but apparently isn't the only name, and in the Django framework it does seems to be called Scrollspy. Thus I'm accepting the answer that mentions both of these; thanks though!